# Sublime text 2: class navigator or browser side bar

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a plug-in (or setting) in sublime2 that shows a side pane with a navigator (or tree view) for the class in an active file?  Someting similar to the class navigator in netbeans?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command to browser the symbols on the current file, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (only available in Sublime Text 3) to browse symbols in all file opened in tabs.

Comment: Been looking for something like this for a while now. Mac users; CMD+R . CMD+SHIFT+R doesn't appear to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

**I think [CTags](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags) is a nice candidate too.**

It uses the `ctags` executable to index all your project files and allow you to browse through symbols in your whole project. Quite impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Using Sublime2, the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is the 'Goto Symbol' option on the 'Goto' menu. You may have remapped it. Whilst it isn't a permanent onscreen navigator (like NetBeans for example), it is pretty quick to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to vote here in order to see this functionality implemented in SublimeText :
http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topics/1265-add-a-class-browser/

In the meantime, `CTRL+R` is the only alternative...

Answer (score 1):

CMD+R and SHIFT+CMD+R are available on Sublime Text 3 for Mac.  CMD+R will browse symbols on the current open file as stated before here, while SHIFT+CMD+R will browse all symbols in all open files if you don't have a ST3 project open, or browse all symbols in all project files if a project is open.